# OpenSSL C RSA library decryption

Tags: c, encryption, rsa

I am using these functions to encrypt and decrypt a text file into an output text file using RSA_public_encrypt and RSA_private_decrypt

While launching the command line program taking as an input public key file name or private key file name, the encryption process is working just fine whereas decryption is always failing.

Below is the encryption file function I am calling that calls readRSAKeyFromFile to return RSA data type, to handle it later on.

If I am missing something here let me know.

I am kind of new to C, and I thought giving a shot trying to write something as a test to understand C basics.

Your help would be very appreciated

void enc_file(char *pub_key_name, char *file_name){

```
    RSA *rsa = readRSAKeyFromFile(pub_key_name, 1);

    char *data_read_from_file;
    long fileSize = 0;

    unsigned char *encrypted_data = (unsigned char*)malloc( RSA_size(rsa) ) ;

    FILE * stream = fopen (file_name, "rb");
    //Seek to the end of the file to determine the file size
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(stream);
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    //Allocate enough memory (add 1 for the \0, since fread won't add it)
    data_read_from_file = malloc(fileSize+1);

    //Read the file
    size_t size=fread(data_read_from_file,1,fileSize,stream);
    data_read_from_file[size]= 0; // Add terminating zero.
    fclose(stream);

    int result = public_key_encryption(data_read_from_file, encrypted_data, rsa);

    free(data_read_from_file);

    FILE * file = fopen("encrypted_data.txt","w+");
    fputs((const char *)encrypted_data,file);
    fclose(file);

    printf(" %s \n", encrypted_data );

    if( result == -1 ){
        perror("Couldn't encrypt file");
    }else{
        printf("[*] Successfully encrypted data \n" );
    }

}


void dec_file(char *priv_key_name, char *file_name){

    RSA *rsa = readRSAKeyFromFile(priv_key_name, 0);

    char *data_read_from_file;
    long fileSize = 0;

    unsigned char *decrypted_data = (unsigned char*)malloc( RSA_size(rsa) ) ;

    FILE * stream = fopen (file_name, "rb");
    //Seek to the end of the file to determine the file size
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(stream);
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    //Allocate enough memory (add 1 for the \0, since fread won't add it)
    data_read_from_file = malloc(fileSize+1);

    //Read the file
    size_t size=fread(data_read_from_file,1,fileSize,stream);
    data_read_from_file[size]= 0; // Add terminating zero.
    fclose(stream);

    int result = private_key_decryption(data_read_from_file, decrypted_data, rsa);

    free(data_read_from_file);

    FILE * file = fopen("encrypted_data.txt","w+");
    fputs((const char *)decrypted_data,file);
    fclose(file);

    printf(" %s \n", decrypted_data );

    if( result == -1 ){
        perror("Couldn't encrypt file");
    }else{
        printf("[*] Successfully decrypted data \n" );
    }

}

RSA * readRSAKeyFromFile(char * filename,int is_public){


    FILE * rsa_pkey_file = fopen(filename,"r");

    if(rsa_pkey_file == NULL){
        printf("ERROR opening file :: %s \n",filename);
        return NULL;
    }

//    RSA * rsa_key=  RSA_new();
    RSA *rsa_pkey = NULL;

    if(is_public == 1 ){
        PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(rsa_pkey_file, &rsa_pkey, NULL, NULL);
    }else{
        PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(rsa_pkey_file, &rsa_pkey, NULL, NULL);
    }

    return rsa_pkey;
}

int public_key_encryption( char *data,  unsigned char *encrypted, RSA *rsa_key){

    int result = RSA_public_encrypt( (int)strlen(data), (const unsigned char*)data, encrypted, rsa_key, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING ) ;
    return result;
}

int private_key_decryption(char * data, unsigned char *decrypted, RSA *rsa_key){

    int result = RSA_private_decrypt((int)strlen(data),(const unsigned char *)data,(unsigned char*)decrypted,rsa_key,RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: RSA is not a good solution for encryption files since the size limit of the data that can be encrypted is limited to the key length. Data encryption is generally done the a symmetric algorithm such as AES.

Answer (score 0):

```
fputs((const char *)encrypted_data,file);
```

The problem is here. The encrypted data is *not* a C-style string, and just casting it to `const char *` and passing it to a function that takes a C-style string will not work.

Comment: what solution could be as an alternative ?

Comment: Hint: public_key_encryption() returns the length of the "encrypted" data (as returned by RSA_public_encrypt() ) ...

Comment: @f0unix Did you notice that your code ignores `result`?

Comment: yes, the problem is it's not encrypting nor decrypting prototype

Comment: @f0unix You really should not use AES for encryption and decryption. It's a primitive used as a component of a system and you're trying to use it as if it was the whole system.